# PI not accessible over USB tether from Android

Tags: networking, usb, ssh

I am trying to connect to my RPI4 with my WiFi card in monitor mode using a USB tether connection, I have setup a static IP on the usb0 interface in the Pi as `192.168.231.212`, my device is using the 231 net for some reason while I am seeing everyone have 42 or 43.

The interface is set to auto and hot plug enabled, having an Ethernet connected for testing purposes shows the interface online with the IP assigned, but I am unable to ssh into that IP from my android.

I can't ping the IP from my Android either.

Edit: Running Kali Linux. It worked once, not ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove static IP on your Raspberry Pi!

Android supports mDNS (Avahi) so just connect with `raspberrypi.local` NOT with IP!

And if you want to find your IP use: `ip a | grep usb0`

Answer (score 0):

So, On android 12 the 2nd last part of the IP Address is dynamic as well. 192.168.x.x, so static configurations won't work.

You can get the IP of the pi peruse by using Nmap as follows, you will need to get the IP of the interface `rndis0` and grab the 2nd last value which would be something like `192.168.x.y`

Then get the IP of the pi
`nmap -sn 192.168.x.0/24`